# Resize glide image in ImageView with collapseMode

Tags: android, imageview, parallax, android-glide

I have a problem with Glide when i try to load in a ImageView parallax.

My picture is 1920x1080 (example: http://www.buildingagamingpcsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Crysis3_Screenshot_TheHunter.jpg) and i try to load in a Image View with height in dp:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

I want the image take all container, but the result is that:
[ImageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9eZg.png)

**What is the code of glide to take this?**

My code is inside a collapsingToolbarLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <!-- Collapser -->
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <!-- Image del detalle -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `android:scaleType` attribute to your ImageView.

If you want to display the pictures in proportion, you can use `centerCrop`.

If you don't want to display the pictures in proportion, you can use `fitXY`.

You can use this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <!-- Collapser -->
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <!-- Image del detalle -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:src="@mipmap/bg_user"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```